# Creating Pandas dataframes with a function of comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called Dir that contains five values: N, S, E, W and C. I've  split them into separate dataframes like so:

```
df_N = df[(df['Dir'] == 'N')]
df_S = df[(df['Dir'] == 'S')]
df_E = df[(df['Dir'] == 'E')]
df_W = df[(df['Dir'] == 'W')]
df_C = df[(df['Dir'] == 'C')]
```

However I'd like to create a function or list comprehension that does this for me so if the values in the data change, I don't have to re-code it.

I've created a list of the values like so:

```
CP_Vals = Series.unique(dftc2['iDir']).tolist()
```

But not having a great deal ofd experience in Python, I'm struggling to create something that automates this. I was thinking something like:

```
for x in CP_Vals:
    df_x = df[(df['iDir'] == '%s' % x)]
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this? You can already get the unique values using `df['Dir'].unique()` so could you not just filter your df using these values rather than create new dfs for each value?

Comment: I'm going to create separate columns for the N, S, E, W and C values to merge on to another dataset.

Comment: You could still achieve this without having to create new dfs just by filtering the master df using the unique values, just a suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the different dataframes you get with the corresponding name of as key. Example -

```
CP_Vals = dftc2['iDir'].unique().tolist()
df_dict = {'df_{}'.format(x): df[(df['iDir'] == x)] for x in CP_Vals}
```

Please note, dictionary comprehension is only available in Python 2.7+. Also, after this you can access a particular DataFrame as `df_dict['df_N']` , etc.

Comment: Probably more readable to rewrite the first line as `dftc2['iDir'].unique().tolist()` IMO

Comment: Just to say thanks for the answers here! It worked really well!